# Document Library toolbar is missing for users with full control

Tags: sharepoint-server

The toolbar (Browse-File-Library) is missing for all users even with Full Control.
Only the site collection admins can see that tool bar
What kind of permissions needed to see that tool bar?
- This not for a certain library, but it affects all the current ones, and even if I create a new one and give full control to the users.
it is not a browser issue, as i tried on both Chrome and I.E 
[image: Admin_View]
[image: Full_Control_View]

Comment: Ribbon is in visible. If not then check out in content editor webpart `#s4-ribbonrow{display: none;}`

Comment: thank you for your reply,
actually as i mentioned it is not for a certain library, but all of sudden it became the same for all the created and the new created one's
any global settings may have this kind of effect?

Comment: Did your master page changed recently?

Comment: Try to compare the HTML/CSS code between users’ and admins’, check if the Browser-File-Library part is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... when I click "Return to Classic Sharepoint" all of the bars appear.